# monotonicity of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know if  the function below is monotonically decreasing for all $a,b >0, a\neq b $

\begin{equation}
x\rightarrow \frac{\sinh^2((a-b)x)}{\sinh(2ax)\sinh(2bx)} \text{, $x >0. $}
\end{equation}

Thank you for you response.

Comment: What is squared in the numerator: ${\rm sinh}$ or its argument only? What is the motivation behind this question? (Sounds like a homework problem to me, and asking homework questions is strongly discouraged at this site.)

Comment: @seva Hi , it is the whole $(\sinh((a-b)x))^2$. Actually it is not a homework problem. It's a green kernel from some operator that I want to study. I tried to study the derivative, but it is not obvious at all.

Comment: It IS monotonically decreasing for $a=b,$ so no need to set $a\neq b.$

Comment: Take logarithms, take derivative, simplify using mathematica, it seems to work out.

Comment: @Suvrit Why don't you take the derivative directly? $(\log f)'=f'/f$ has the same sign as $f'$.

Comment: @FanZheng I did so directly first, but the resulting objects looked a bit simpler after taking logarithms, so I recommended it.

Comment: @Survit, I took the derivative of the log and used Jensen mean inequality  to proof that the derivative is negative, and it works :). Thanks a lot again.